# Do gel spheres hold up to heat?

Tags: heat, carrots, spherification

I want to plate a carrot sphere, made using [reverse spherification](https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/reverse-spherification), for a hot entrée. How do carrot spheres hold up to heat?

Answer (score 3):

Alginate gels are heat-stable up-to 150C. So you can easily serve them on a hot plate at the serving temperature.